# NSTableView no selection highlight, but keep track of what row is selected

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I've seen some threads with a similar question to this (not exactly the same) but the solutions there didn't solve my problem. I've create a NSTableView with a couple clickable elements in each TableCellView -- a TextField, a DatePicker and a Button -- and I need to be able to click into each of these without first selecting the row they are in. I achieved this by using `setSelectionHighlightStyle: NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone` However, I still need to know the index of the row that is being edited, because I need to pass the edits into a model object associated with each row. I tried writing the following, which was the suggestion of some of the other threads I mentioned, but it didn't do anything.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldTrackCell:(NSCell *)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    return YES;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if that's the wrong method to use for this, or if I'm just implementing it incorrectly. Any tips on how I could go about this would be awesome.

---

**Edit:**

Here's my attempt at implementing Steve Waddicor's suggestions:

Making the ViewController the NSTableViewDataSource and set the TableCellView as the delegates for the objects (code is in MyViewController.m):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
}
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    CustomTableCellView *view = [self.tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier" owner:self];
    [view.textField setDelegate:view];
    [view.datePicker setDelegate:view];
    return view;
}


//-----------------------
//-----------------------
//----------------------- NSTableViewDataSource Protocol Requirements:


- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return [self.tableView numberOfRows];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return [self.tableView rowViewAtRow:rowIndex makeIfNecessary:NO];
}
```

and in CustomTableCellView, this is the delegate method which isn't being called when I click on the TextField, which leads me to believe that the delegates aren't being set for the objects correctly:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent*) theEvent{
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}
```

Comment: You are indeed using a view-based table view, not a cell-based table view, correct?

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Yes it is view-based

Comment: You can find the index of the most recently clicked row (regardless of whether or not it is selected) by sending your table view the `-clickedRow` message. Example: `NSInteger index = self.tableView.clickedRow`. If that doesn't work, you can always subclass `NSTableRowView` and add a property of `representedObject`, `objectValue`, or whatever name you want. Then using the `NSTableViewDelegate` method `-tableView:rowViewForRow:`, you can assign a model object to your newly created property when you return the row view. Continued in next comment …

Comment: Once that's taken care of, just watch for a first responder change, get the row view using `NSTableView`'s `rowViewAtRow:makeIfNecessary:` method. Then you can get the model by querying your property. If I'm not making any sense, just let me know, and I'll try to explain it better. Good luck! Edit: I just now realized we're not in 2013 anymore. Doh! Oh well, hopefully someone may find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the your tableCellView as the delegate of the controls.  From there you could

```
NSTableView* tableView = self.superview;
NSUInteger row = [tableView rowForView:self];
```

**Edit**

To make a delegate.  In your tableView dataSource you have a method something like this:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    MyTableCellView* view = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier" owner:self];
    [view.textField setDelegate:view];        
    [view.datePicker setDelegate:view];        
    [view.button setDelegate:view];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but I'm having trouble setting the tableCellView as the delegate for the controls. (sorry, i've never tried to do this before). In the `initWithCoder:` method I have `[self.assignmentName setDelegate:self];` to try to set the delegate for the TextField, but I don't think it's working because when I click on it while running the program, the `mouseDown:` method isn't called.

Comment: I don't know what assignmentName in you program is, or which class has the initWithCoder that you mention. I'll update my answer with some generic code.

Comment: Sorry I realize my comment was vague, i tried to edit it a little later but it wouldn't let me. I've edited my original post with the code I've written in trying to implement what you're saying. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Ah, OK.  Well mouseDown isn't a delegate method. Delegates methods of controls are  `-(void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(id)sender`, `-(void)controlTextDidChange:(id)sender`, and `-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(id)sender`, plus some other more specific ones. Try using `controlTextDidBeginEditing`.

Comment: Just replaced `mouseDown` with `controlTextDidBeginEditing` and still no result. I think I may have figured out a way around using delegates, by subclassing the TextField class and overriding the mouseDown method to send a message to the TableViewCell to set the row of the ViewController to the row of the TableViewCell. Not sure if that's bad form or not. In the TextField class, would self.superview return the TableViewCell that it's in?

Comment: Also, the line `NSUInteger row = [tableView rowForView:self];` doesn't work because it returns -1 if the class isn't a TableRowView and mine is a TableCellView. Is there a method like this that would work for TableCellView? I can't find anything in the class reference

Answer (score 1):

try this delegate

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is working, because it still isn't recognizing when the selection is changing (ie. `tableViewSelectionDidChange:` isn't being called.)